# I can't load a javascript scatter plot in any browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer-11, activex, scatter-plot

Recently, maybe after updating Java, I'm unable to load a scatter plot on Chrome, Firefox or Internet Explorer.

One month ago, everything loaded fine. I don't know what happened. I've updated Java to the last version and enabled ActiveX on Internet options, but nothing works for me.

I'll paste the html code. It loads the point info using a csv file saved in the same folder:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <meta charset="utf-8"> <style>
body { font: 12px Arial;}
.axis path, .axis line { fill: none; stroke: grey; stroke-width: 1;
shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
</style> <body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script> <script>
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60}, width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right, height = 360 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
// Parse the date / time
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y "); // Set the ranges
var y = d3.scaleTime().range([height, 0]); var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
// Define the axes
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x) .ticks(5);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y)
.ticks(5);
// Adds the svg canvas var svg = d3.select("body") .append("svg")
.attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right) .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom) .append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // Get the data
d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) { var max = data.length; console.log(max)
data.forEach(function(d, i) { d.dateParsed = parseDate(d.date); d.close = max - i;
}); // Scale the range of the data
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dateParsed; })); x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
// Add the scatterplot svg.selectAll("dot") .data(data)
.enter().append("circle") .attr("r", 0.5)
.attr("fill","#2980B9")
.attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.dateParsed); }) .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.close); });
svg.append("g") .attr("class", "x axis")
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") .call(xAxis);
svg.append("text") .attr("class", "x label") .attr("text-anchor", "middle") .attr("x", width / 2) .attr("y", height + 40) .text("followers");
svg.append("g")
.attr("class", "y axis") .call(yAxis);
svg.append("text") .attr("class", "y label") .attr("text-anchor", "middle") .attr("x", -height / 2 ) .attr("y", -50)
.attr("transform", "rotate(-90)") .text("account creation date");
});
</script> </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like main issue is code is not formatted properly.

Many comments get mixed with the code caused the syntax errors.

I try to format the code and try to fix those errors.

As we don't have your data.csv file so we are not able to load that data but code creates the chart now.

You can try to use this code on your side with your data.csv file. It will help you to load the chart properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <style>
      body { font: 12px Arial;}
      .axis path, .axis line { fill: none; stroke: grey; stroke-width: 1;
      shape-rendering: crispEdges; }
   </style>
</head>
   <body>
      <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script> <script>
         // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph 
         var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 60}, width = 900 - margin.left - margin.right, height = 360 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
         // Parse the date / time
         var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y "); // Set the ranges
         var y = d3.scaleTime().range([height, 0]); var x = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
         // Define the axes
         var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x) .ticks(5);
         var yAxis = d3.axisLeft().scale(y)
         .ticks(5);
         // Adds the svg canvas 
         var svg = d3.select("body") .append("svg")
         .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right) .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")"); // Get the data
         d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) { var max = data.length; 
         console.log(max);
         data.forEach(function(d, i) { d.dateParsed = parseDate(d.date); d.close = max - i;
         }); 
     // Scale the range of the data
         y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.dateParsed; })); x.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);
         // Add the scatterplot 
         svg.selectAll("dot") .data(data)
         .enter().append("circle") .attr("r", 0.5)
         .attr("fill","#2980B9")
         .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.dateParsed); }) .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.close); });
         svg.append("g") .attr("class", "x axis")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")") .call(xAxis);
         svg.append("text") .attr("class", "x label") .attr("text-anchor", "middle") .attr("x", width / 2) .attr("y", height + 40) .text("followers");
         svg.append("g")
         .attr("class", "y axis") .call(yAxis);
         svg.append("text") .attr("class", "y label") .attr("text-anchor", "middle") .attr("x", -height / 2 ) .attr("y", -50)
         .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)") .text("account creation date");
         });
      </script> 
   </body>
</html>
```